# Invisible mouse pointer when recording screen on a remote PC

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, mouse, vnc, screen-capture

What I'm trying to do is record videos on a remote server.

The issue is that when I use any other remote control application other than the native windows remote desktop, the mouse pointer is never visible in recorder videos. I tried teamviewer, vnc, java vnc, radmin, logmein and others.

For example in teamviewer, the mouse cursor is visible on the screen (you can see it on the remote machine), however in the recorded video the cursor is invisible.

Every recording software behaves the same (bandicam, camtasia and others).

I tried changing mouse pointer settings, windows themes and other things.

The issue I'm describing is happening only in Windows 8.1 and Windows 2012 Server R2. The Windows 2008 Server is working perfectly fine, via teamviewer and other applications, however I need it to work under 8 or 2012.

The host machine has integrated graphics and up to date drivers (Intel HD Graphics 4000), and the reason why I'm trying to avoid remote desktop is that I need to be able to record videos on multiple user accounts simultaneously, and Windows 2012 Server has the limit of 2 concurrent RDP connections.

I'd appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try VLC media player to record your desktop screen? VLC player has screen recording feature with customize f/s (frames per second) and different file format(like .mp4, avi, mkv etc.). Try VLC media player.

See the link [useful tricks on VLC media player](http://www.001easytricks.com/2014/08/vlc-media-player-tricks.html) to know how to use it as screen recorder.

Answer (score 0):

In the third party program called fraps, there's an option to record the mouse too, same as the program Camtasia.

It sounds weird to me, are you use there's no option in teamviewer as well?